# MYSQL joining three tables if field is not null

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables in my database that I want to join if a join-field in table 1 is not null. If it is null I want only the results of table 1.

```
Table1
----------------------
id | name | table2_id|
----------------------
1    John    1
2    Frank   1
3    Mary    2
4    Susan   null

Table2
----------------------
id | City | table3_id|
----------------------
1    Berlin   2
2    Paris    3
3    Rome     1
3    Oslo     1

Table3
-------------------------------
id | title       | description | 
-------------------------------
1    Great place    Some tekst
2    Fun town       Some other text
3    Don't go       More text
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT a.name, b.city, c.title, c.description
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON b.id = a.table2_id
LEFT JOIN table3 AS c ON c.id = b.table3_id
WHERE a.id = 1
```

This works fine as long as table1 has a table2_id. In the case of John it returns

```
John, Berlin, Great Place, Some text
```

But in the case of Susan the table2_id is null, so it returns an empty result. But I want to have 'Susan' as a result.

Comment: is it ok that you have `3    Rome     1; 
3    Oslo     1` . ?

Comment: I get a row for Susan: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n2q66M2HbEvM7kkwHE2q6F/1

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1461e/2

Comment: So do I: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nqW1TzuSHyzVsmqMfnELHW/0

Comment: LEFT JOIN should ensure you get any table1 entry to ask for; but if your real query has conditions on "table2" or "table3" in the WHERE clause, you are effectively turning it's join into an INNER JOIN.

Comment: It works fine itself.

Comment: I figured out where I went wrong. In my real-life query the join between tables 2 and 3 was set as an INNER JOIN. That will only work if you are certain the rows in table 1 all have an id that connects with table 2..